# Can't click on a radioButton with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I seemingly can't click on a radio button on [this](https://www.panerabread.com/en-us/mypanera/registration-page.html) website. Everything else works, however when I try to click on the radioButton that says "I don't have a MyPanera card", it simply gives me an error. Here is my code for that part:

```
radioButton = browser.find_element_by_id("mypanera_card_info")
radioButton.click()
```

Comment: As the answers have said, you need to use the id "join_card_not_available". Try that and if that doesn't work, please update your question with the code you are using and the error.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Do have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `id` you are looking for is `join_card_not_available`. `mypanera_card_info` is the value of the `name` attribute for that tag. Try this:

```
radioButton = browser.find_element_by_id("join_card_not_available")
radioButton.click()
```

**EDIT:** The element you want to click on should be in the visible part of the screen. Try scrolling down a bit & also set an implicit wait for the webdriver (just as a safety measure).

```
browser = webdriver.Somthing()
browser.execute_script("$('#join_password').get(0).scrollIntoView();")
browser.implicitly_wait(10)

# And then perform the click
browser.find_element_by_id("join_card_not_available").click()
```

Comment: I tried using that earlier but every time I do that one it goes to the homepage of panera.com. Not sure why.

Comment: How do I submit the form at the end?

Comment: Let me have a look at the site again.

Comment: For some reason I'm unable to submit the form using `find_element_by_id`. I'm guessing you are facing the same issue. I still can't figure out why it can't find the button. But for now you can use this: `driver.execute_script("$('#join-now-primary').click();")`.

Comment: It doesn't work, because it just sends you back to the panera home page without submitting the form though.

Answer (score 0):

The radio button's `id` is not `"mypanera_card_info"`, it's `"join_card_not_available"`:

```
<input type="radio" id="join_card_not_available" name="mypanera_card_info">
```

Either use

```
browser.find_element_by_id("join_card_not_available")
```

or

```
browser.find_element_by_name("mypanera_card_info")
```

Comment: The weird thing about using that is as soon as it gets to that point in the script, it submits the entire thing or something and goes to the homepage of panera. Not sure why it does that. All I know is that it only does that when I use that line.

Comment: Perhaps the code which follows this line doesn't work as you expected? This code usually wouldn't be hit since it would usually error before that point.

Going to the page you linked and executing `document.getElementById("join_card_not_available").click()` works exactly as you'd expect, clicking the radio button and nothing else, so I'd assume the error is not in that line.